# How to use knife tool in python?

Tags: python, knife-tool

I want my script to cut geometry faces with knife tool. I read about `bpy.ops.mesh.knife_tool()` but there's no parameter for specifying the cut path. Is there an example or reference on how to use knife tool through python script?

Comment: There is no bmesh equivalent of knife tool